# Alt+Enter in intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am writing scala code in IntelliJ. I use a class,which gives me multiple options on Alt+Enter, as shown below:

[image]

What I see is that both options are exactly same.Even 'exclude' options(as shown in image) are same for both.

So are they two different options or what?

Comment: "Even 'exclude' options(as shown in image) are same for both." – Are they? They don't look the same to me. In fact, you don't even have to read them to see that one is longer than the other and thus *cannot possibly* be the same.

Comment: Those two 'exclude' entries  are shown when i select one of the two options. So when I select other one, then again these 2 'exclude' entries are shown. That way  they are same. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: Try to use both. You will probably end up with the same import added to your class. So it's intellij bug. Nothing critical though.

Comment: @Mandroid bug report is welcome at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL.